# Plc4x addressing system

Tags: apache-plc4x

I am discovering the Plc4x java implementation which seems to be of great interest in our field. But the youth of the project and the documentation makes us hesitate. I have been able to implement the basic hello world for reading out of our PLCs, but I was unable to write. I could not find how the addresses are handled and what the `maskwrite`, `andMask` and `orMask` fields mean.

Please can somebody explain to me the following example and detail how the addresses should be used?

```
    @Test
    void testWriteToPlc() {
        // Establish a connection to the plc using the url provided as first argument
        try( PlcConnection plcConnection = new PlcDriverManager().getConnection( "modbus:tcp://1.1.2.1" ) ){
            // Create a new read request:
            // - Give the single item requested the alias name "value"
            var builder = plcConnection.writeRequestBuilder();
            builder.addItem( "value-" + 1, "maskwrite:1[1]/2/3", 2 );
            var writeRequest = builder.build();

            LOGGER.info( "Synchronous request ..." );
            var syncResponse = writeRequest.execute().get();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used PLC4x for writing using the modbus driver with success. Here is some sample code I am using:

```
public static void writePlc4x(ProtocolConnection connection, String registerName, byte[] writeRegister, int offset)
    throws InterruptedException {

    // modbus write works ok writing one record per request/item
    int size = 1;
    PlcWriteRequest.Builder writeBuilder =  connection.writeRequestBuilder();

    if (writeRegister.length == 2) {
      writeBuilder.addItem(registerName, "register:" + offset + "[" + size + "]", writeRegister);
    }
...
    PlcWriteRequest request = writeBuilder.build();
    request.execute().whenComplete((writeResponse, error) -> {
      assertNotNull(writeResponse);
    });
    Thread.sleep((long) (sleepWait4Write * writeRegister.length * 1000));
}
```

In the case of modbus writing there is an issue regarding the return of the writer Future, but the write is done. In the modbus use case I don't need any mask stuff.